# php shell_exec multiple commands at once in background

Tags: php, linux, plesk

I have a problem in php/linux, described below:

I have to execute  a linux command through shell_exec (plesk cli command subscription webspace-off).

The problem is when i do this from php it works, but restarts apache, that resulting in a blank page, while apache restarts.

To get rid of the problem i have to call that shell_exec in background, with a delay (Expected result: the web page loads, and after 4 sec. runs the linux script.)

I have done some tryings  like:

```
shell_exec("sleep 4 && /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/wrapper2 3  --webspace-off ".$domain_name." &");
```

but php will wait for response.

Somehow i need to sleep the execution of a linux command , and all this has to run in bg.,
and dont wait for response.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should try using [`exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) rather than `shell_exec`, and redirect all output to `/dev/null`. Something like:

```
exec("(sleep 4 && ... --webspace-off ".$domain_name.") > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

(Note the `()` around the commands: you need to catch the output stream of both `sleep` and your wrapper.)

Edit: and make **real** sure that you validate `$domain_name`. Without validation and with

```
$domain_name = "; rm -rf ...";
```

you're in trouble...

Comment: throwing all output to `/dev/null` saved my night! Thanks!