# running php exec command in background

Tags: php, exec

I am attempting to launch sar and have it run forever via a php script.  But for whatever reason it never actually launches.  I have tried the following:

```
exec('sar -u 1 > /home/foo/foo.txt &');
exec('sar -o /home/foo/foo -u 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

However it never launches sar.  If I just use:

```
exec('sar -u 1')
```

It works but it just hangs the php script.  My understanding that if a program is started with exec function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream.

Comment: Why start it with a PHP script if you want it to run forever?

Comment: Its part of an asterisk agi script that executes a php script to start it.  Then after a series of events another php script is called to stop it.  In the case above though it will never actually start and run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume your running this on a *nix platform.  To get php to run something in the background and not wait for the process to finish I would recommend 2 things:  First use `nohup` and also redirect the output of the command to `/dev/null` (trash).

Example:

```
<?php
exec('nohup sar -u 1 > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

**nohup** means we do not send the "hang up" signal (which kills the process) when the terminal running the command closes.

**`> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &`** [redirects the "normal" and "error" outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8962081/1356593) to the blackhole `/dev/null` location.  This allows PHP to not have to wait for the outputs of the command being called.

On another note, if you are using PHP *just* to call a shell command, you may want to consider other options like [Ubuntu's Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) with no PHP component--if you are using Ubuntu that is.

Comment: Ok that works if I run it solely with PHP.  Thanks.  Must be an issue with asterisks script execution then.